# Display Relevent Field Label Depending On Selection From asp:DropDownList Potentially Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an `Asp.net` application and on click of a button I have a modal which first of all only displays my dropdown list. Then when the user selects an option, additional fields are displayed.

The thing is, is that rather than keep duplicating code, I'd like to be able to just replace my `asp:label` depending on the selection made.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAction" runat="server" Class="col-sm-4 control-label" Text="Select Action" AssociatedControlID="ddActionList" />
<div class="col-sm-8">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddActionList" runat="server" class="form-control" style="max-width: 95%" >
          <asp:ListItem Value="0">- - Please Select - -</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">Add A New User</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="2">Add A New Place</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="3">Remove An Existing User</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="4">Report A Bug</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="5">Site Imporovement</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="6">Other</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div id="Allfields" hidden>
     <asp:Label ID="lblFirstField" runat="server" Class="col-sm-4 control-label" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstField" />
     <div class="col-sm-8">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstField" runat="server" class="form-control" style="max-width: 95%" />
     </div>
</div>
```

**Current Jquery Which Does Show/Hide**

```
$("#MainContent_ddActionList").change(function ()
{
    if ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 0)
    {
        $("#Allfields").hide();
    }
    else if ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 6)
    {
        $("#Allfields").show();
        $("#OtherSelected").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Allfields").show();
        $("#OtherSelected").hide();
    }            
});
```

Not sure how to do it.

**Examples**

If the user selects:

- 'Add User' I want to display 'Enter Name'
- 'Add Place' I want to display 'Enter Place Name'

I don't want to add extra code if this can be done which I suspect it can, but I just don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by updating my `JQuery` to the following:

```
    $("#MainContent_ddActionList").change(function ()
    {
        if ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 0)
        {
            $("#Allfields").hide();
            $("#OtherSelected").hide();
        }
        else if (($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 1) || ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 2) || ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 3))
        {
            $("#Allfields").show();
            $("#OtherSelected").hide();
            $("#MainContent_lblFirstField").text('Enter Full Name')
        }
        else if ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 4) {
            $("#Allfields").show();
            $("#OtherSelected").hide();
            $("#MainContent_lblFirstField").text('Page')
        }
        else if ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 5) {
            $("#Allfields").show();
            $("#OtherSelected").hide();
            $("#MainContent_lblFirstField").text('Suggested By')
        }
        else if ($("#MainContent_ddActionList").val() == 6)
        {
            $("#Allfields").show();
            $("#OtherSelected").show();
            $("#MainContent_lblFirstField").text('Reported By')
        }      
    });
```